# Do we need to install the Universal forwarder in the host(Log originating Server) for scripted inputs?

Tags: splunk

I need to forward some database related logs into splunk indexer using scripted inputs (Shell scripts)

My questions are :

1)Do I need to install the universal forwarder in the host side ?

2)Is there any other way rather than installing UF in host that we can extract the logs into indexer using scripted inputs?

3)In order to accomplish this what are the steps do I need to follow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To run a scripted input you need either a Universal Forwarder or a Heavy Forwarder.  You'll need the HF to run a Python script.

2) See @Akah's answer.

3) See http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Forwarder/7.2.1/Forwarder/Abouttheuniversalforwarder

Comment: Thanks @RichG , I had installed the universal forwarder in the host ,and developing the script as well. kindly share any other information in getting the scripted inputs data into indexer .

Comment: Information about getting data into Splunk can be found in their excellent documentation at http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.1/Data/Getstartedwithgettingdatain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTTP Event Collector](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/UsetheHTTPEventCollector) which permits you to send data to the indexer via HTTP in JSON format.
There are examples to show you how to do via curl (and so by script) :

```
curl -k https://<host>:8088/services/collector -H 'Authorization: Splunk <token>' -d '{"sourcetype": "mysourcetype", "event":"Hello, World!"}'
```

You can follow [the walkthrough](http://dev.splunk.com/view/event-collector/SP-CAAAE7F) too.